# How do I link my phpmyadmin to my php using MAMP?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I've just switched from using WAMP hosting to MAMP, and I'm not sure how to connect my database to it, I've tried using the same format but it won't be connecting.

Here's my connection code:

```
<?php

$dbServername = "localhost:8888"
$dbUsername = "root"
$dbPassword = ""
$dbName = "databasename"

$conn = mysqli_connect($dbServername, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbName)
```

Comment: You should be getting parse errors here, as posted.

Comment: Is the database really at port 8888? Not 3306 (default)? Also, ports needs to be specified at the 5th parameter in `mysqli_connect()`.

Comment: Check your PHP error logs.  Check `mysqli_connect_error()`.  The system is telling you what's wrong, you just have to look.

Comment: How do I get my php errors? Sorry if I don't know much I'm new to MAMP and php all together..